# How long I need to practice piano in general before trying to learn playing blues?

Tags: piano, blues

Is playing blues understood as advanced skill or something that it is possible to **start** learning without significant background?

I basically know which notes are which on the keyboard and can play some simple melodies from my textbook. How important is to spend more time on general studies? Blues seems attractive for me because of the rhythm and possibility of improvisation.

Comment: until you learn the blues scales

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of blues numbers are built around the 12-bar sequence. This is, in its simplest form, I I I I IV IV I I V IV I V. Put this in, say, C,and the chord sequence is four bars of C, two bars of F, two bars of C, one of G, one of F, one of C, and the turnaround chord of G. Each of these sounds more bluesy with the added b7. So the first C7 chord will contain C-E-G and Bb. Play these as block chords, or arpeggiate them: playing C-E-G-Bb on each beat in each bar will be a start for you.(This is left hand accompaniment, for you to improvise with right hand over it).

You should start NOW !!There's no need to get any more knowledge in order to get going !

Answer (score 3):

You don't say how much musical knowledge you have away from piano. I play guitar, I've never studied piano and I don't own a keyboard instrument. But I can play bluesy stuff on the piano no problem. Here's a bluffer's guide to playing blues in the key of Am/C which is of course the easiest key to play on piano.

Right hand: Blues scale `A C D Eb E G.` the Eb gives it the bluesy feel, especially if you play `A C D Eb!`. You might get away with throwing in a B, but an F will sound way too jolly.

Left hand: play an `A5` (E+A, with the E low.) Following the blues progression, introduce `D5` (A+D) and `E5` (B+E). To give more variation, build up rhythms by adding 6ths and 7ths (the notes in between the ones you are already playing.

The opening of Beethoven's Fur Elise follows a blues scale an makes an awesome crossover piece if you change the rhythm slightly.

Note: by `A5` I mean A with no third. This term is common in rock, not sure if it is used in classical.

Comment: Most people play left hand 5 chords with the root note at the bottom.  The blues notes you mention also work when the key is A major. Especially when one plays with another person who can/will play the dom.7th chords, or even just the majors.                                              Interesting reference to Fur Elise !

Comment: @tim 1.sure, but if you're a total beginner, playing a root and 5th and then adding in a 6th or 7th for colour is a long stretch for your hand. As I say, this is a bluffer's guide. 2. Correct again, but I like my blues to be moody. With A major I might call it rock and roll.

Comment: .@Steve.1. most grown ups can reach an octave, even as beginners, and a b7 under a root can sound quite 'muddy'.2. It's subjective, but I've always said that maj.3 ought to be part of the blues notes. How many blues players out there DON'T use it in their solos?

Comment: @tim your points are completely valid and I'm glad you made them, they add to my answer. But my main point is there's no reason not to learn blues from the very start if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just start doing it. Obvious starting point is to just play around with the blues scale.